# How to enable HTTP requests using Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

While I'm in the development environment, I have no issues with HTTP calls. However, after my project is built and uploaded for internal testing via Google Play Console, and I install the store's APK, HTTP requests are not allowed. With React Native without Expo, I know I can adjust this using:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

But I don't know how to do this with Expo without having to create and generate the iOS and Android folders.

I created a `network_security_config.xml` file and added it to the `app.json` like this:

```json
"expo": {
  ...
  "android": {
    "config": {
      "networkSecurityConfig": "./network_security_config.xml"
    },
  ...
  }
}
```

But it didn't work because the `networkSecurityConfig` field does not exist.

I am using React Native 0.72.4 and Expo 49.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Which library are you using for your HTTP requests?

Personally, i use Axios in my application and it works fine. In development, preview && on internal testing.

Comment: I use axios too, I had this problem before but I solved it by going through the api gateway to get the certificate, but now I can't do that

Answer (score 0):

hope im not too late, if you're building your application with expo eas, you can still enable CleartextTraffic from your app.config.js or app.json
with the [expo-build-properties](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/)

inside your app.config.js in plugins should be

```
[
  'expo-build-properties',
  {
    android: {
      usesCleartextTraffic: true, // ? enable HTTP requests
    },
    ios: {
      flipper: true,
    },
  },
],
```

for ios is

```
  ios: {
    infoPlist: {
      NSAppTransportSecurity: { NSAllowsArbitraryLoads: true }, // ? enable HTTP requests
    },
    supportsTablet: true,
  },
```