# Expo react native - ERROR [TypeError: Network request failed] only in production after updating

Tags: react-native, expo

Please note this is not related to localhost error [ERROR [TypeError: Network request failed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78039013/error-typeerror-network-request-failed)

Today I updated the Expo platform and related libraries due to it complaining about incompatibilites. I downloaded the latest version of Node as well and installed it. I messed up my project. This project is an app that makes a simple fetch to a local DB to obtain data. Note that the previous version of the app still works perfectly, which tells me the problem is not on the server side.
Now, the new version throws a Network request failed but only in production. In the development build using npx expo start does not complain, nor does the expo go screen.
I wonder what's causing this issue and I think I am not wrong finding the culprit around version incompatibilities. As said, I'm not using "localhost" anywhere and serverside provides correctly previous versions of the app.

Here a list of the current versions being used:

- npm: 10.2.4
- Node: 20.11.1
- expo: 6.3.10
- npx expo version: 0.17.5
- npx eas --version shows: eas-cli/7.3.0 win32-x64 node-v17.5.0

I have no clue what's causing the production unable to make a simple fetch.

Here my relative code (hiding sensible data).

```
const localUrl = `http://192.1xx.x.x:xxxx/vent/${valor}`;
const controller = new AbortController();
const signal = controller.signal;
const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(localUrl, { signal: signal });
      if (!response?.ok || !response) {
        console.log("Details:", response);//can't see this in Android production
        throw new Error("Error de response: "+ response?.statusText);//here throws the error
      }
    }
    //...code continues with catch MyToast(error.message, 10, "error");
}
```

I also tried to run gradle locally but the task couldn't finish due to an error with

```
react-native-community_netinfo:androidJdkImage
```

which I don't know until what point it may be related.

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 9, accessing HTTP urls is disabled by default in release mode.

[This topic (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76475785/add-usescleartexttraffic-true-on-expo-react-native) might help you overcome this, but keep in mind that using HTTP instead of HTTPS is not recommended.

Comment: Thank you, nowadays obtaining an answer here is really difficult, i appreciate it. I applied the code mentioned in your link, but the issue persisted, I used the one here as well, but no solution so far:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77157620/how-to-enable-http-requests-using-expo